# Доступ к текстовому вводу других приложений

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Идея приложения похожа на PuntoSwitcher. Человек что-то вводит в NotePad, Word, IE... и по нажатию на комбинацию горячих клавиш должен активировать утилит, которая изменит текст, вводимый в выбранный в данный момент текстовый редактор. Сама утилита не имеет активного окна и фокус ввода не получает. Должна работать, начиная с Windows Vista.

Как в утилите получить текст другого приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Vista можно интенсивно использовать [текстовые службы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629032(v=vs.85).aspx): это проще, чем хуки, и возможностей по вводу больше.

Или навесить низкоуровневые хуки и следить за фокусом и текстовым вводом, как предлагает cy6erGn0m.

Answer (score 1):

[GetActiveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + надо найти способ понять, какое окно в окне сейчас имеет фокус ввода .. что-то вроде [GetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), но в чужом окне.

Второй вариант, это слушать все нажатия клавиш и нажатия мыши, как делают кейлоггеры.

Comment: Этот вариант будет работать только в одном процессе. Активное окно другого процесса так не получить.

Answer (score 1):

Сабклассинг в пределах одного приложения, хуки(фильтры) и прочие механизмы глобально.